# Container runs systemd, what's the easiest way to execute a script that uses systemd?

Tags: centos, systemd, container, buildah

I have a container that runs systemd, the setup instructions followed can be found at

- [*Dockerfile for systemd base image*](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos)

Now I have a script `install.sh` which I need to run in the build phase over the base image created above. The problem is that the `install.sh` is systemd aware.

So what is the easiest way to have systemd's init run that `install.sh`, what I want is something like

```
buildah run $ctr -- sh /tmp/install.sh
```

But this will **not** run `install.sh` under systemd, as I require.

Comment: What is the error message ? Try buildah run $ctr -- sh -c '/tmp/install.sh'

Comment: That won't work because `sh` in that example will not magically start systemd.

Answer (score 0):

I used to build the same systemd image with buildah and tried to execute a simple script and it works fine ; maybe i am missing something :

```
 buildah run -t -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro  onbuild-image-working-container-2  sh -c 'cat /tmp/install.sh'
--> #!/bin/bash
--> echo lol

buildah run -t -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro  onbuild-image-working-container-2  sh -c 'chmod 777 /tmp/install.sh && /tmp/install.sh'
--> lol
```

OUTPUT :
lol

**SINCE your last comment: Using here docker**

**BUILDAH** is meant for building **OCI** images, so if you are using in parallel **podman** or **docker** just use push the image to a **local registry** using **buildah** after building **systemd-image** from Dockerfile and mount /sys/fs/cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup with **read-only** options so it wont override your systemd cgroups :

```
buildah bud --format=docker -f Dockerfile -t onbuild-image <path_to_DockerFile>
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
buildah push --tls-verify=false onbuild-image docker://localhost:5000/systemd-centos:latest
docker pull localhost:5000/systemd-centos:latest
ctr1="$(docker run -d -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -p 8000:80 localhost:5000/systemd-centos)"
docker exec -it $ctr1 'systemctl'
```

Comment: Because these are just commands you're running. You're not actually making use of systemd, and you're not starting init. Try making a call to systemctl for example, on your host machine and in your container. One of them works, one of them doesn't.

Comment: Check the edit i maid. It's functional and tested

Comment: I'm not using docker anywhere. In your example though what's happening is you're using special images and running init manually. Then execing what you want to run. That works, but that's not what I want. I want to run the image and have init spawn the desired process.

Comment: So buildah is not meant for that.