# Is there a way to expose ports after a container is running?

Tags: networking, container, podman

Podman gives a mechanism to expose ports with

> `--expose=port` Expose a port, or a range of ports (e.g. `--expose=3300-3310`) to set up port redirection on the host system.

Is there a mechanism to set this option on a running container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to edit the container networking settings during the runtime without stopping it and recreate it with the needed port to expose.

Here is the [parameters](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_update/) you can update during the runtime.

Comment: Check this link https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_update/

Comment: Also check my answer on your previous post :  [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/619526/container-runs-systemd-whats-the-easiest-way-to-execute-a-script-that-uses-sys/619541?noredirect=1#comment1158783_619541)